# What degree of magnetic shielding does a Kozyrev Mirror require?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, shielding

After learning about kozyrev mirrors, I’m curious what types of fields they’re designed to shield. “The earth’s electromagnetic field” was all I could find. But does that mean just earths magnetic field, the field shown by a compass? Or also the the ELF of the Schumann resonance? Or both? How is a kozyrev mirror related to a zero gauss chamber, one and the same or no?

Also, what materials does it require to match the required degree of shielding?

Comment: i think that a kozyrev mirror provides similar shielding as an aluminum foil hat

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is pseudoscience.

Comment: Because Wikipedia says so? Open your mind. I guess you just don’t have an answer. There’s nothing pseudoscience about magnetic shielding.

Comment: there’s plenty of places to discuss these kinds of things without trying to foist them onto a site for engineering, which is based on... wait for it... *science*.

Comment: You don’t have the understanding, that’s fine. Don’t answer or comment. Leave that for someone who does.

Comment: Here’s some...wait for it...**science** for you. http://www.altaibooks.com/trofimov.pdf

Comment: Smells like... bullshit. Filled with bafflegab and false appeals to authority - two classic hallmarks of pseudoscience. Not making your case so well there, Jim.

Comment: Jim this is about as realistic as america trialing thought control via LSD in the 60's... Did smart people work on it in nice labs, yep. Did they write a lot of notes and descriptions of their amazing tests, yep... Did it ever work? Nope.

Comment: The article tells you, the cosmobiotron uses sheets of mumetal, well known for having a permeability much higher than ordinary steel, and potentially useable for magnetic sheilding. Now according to wikipedia, Kozrev mirrors use glass, or aluminium. About the only thing these materials can have in common is their shape, Sad story for Kozrev, he was gulag'd for 20 years during the Stalinist purges. He mused on the power source of stars, but in his isolation didn't hear of the discovery of atomic energy, sounds like he never got over the shock when he was released, and refused to believe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want magnetic shielding, then use sheets of metal.

The standard PCB thickness foil, 35 microns or 1.4 mils, have a few dB effect at 4MHz (1 neper of attenuation), 3 nepers of attenuation at 40MHz and 10 nepers (87dB) at 400MHz.

For low frequency magnetic protection, you either need much thicker copper, or switch to steel.

Read up on "skin depth" for some guidance.